# Rails 3 - Append value to a field to many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say I have a bunch of records with a string field. I now want to append a constant string to that field to every record. For example, I may have records with "Wall" and "Page" as values for the field, but what if I want them to be "WallPost" and "PagePost"? I know I can cycle through every record and update it individually, but is there a better way to do this (with an `update_all`, I presume). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to append/prepend something to your string to every value, you will have to iterate through all values. The `update_all` doesn't let you get the `self` scope of each object, so i believe you will have to cycle and update.